# Setup Postfix as a fake server similar to Neptune and Papercut

Tags: postfix

I would like to configure Postfix in out dev and stage environment to only save the emails like Papercut and Neptune?

It's very important that the actual emails are not sent but only saved, to be able to check them as part of the QA work.

Answer (score 4):

Use a regular expression map to rewrite all recipients. As long as your email is submitted via SMTP, this will suffice.

In main.cf

```
virtual_alias_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/recipients
```

In /etc/postfix/recipients

```
\#user@example.com is a mailbox where QA will receive email
/.+/   user@example.com
```

Answer (score 2):

Why setup a fully fledged mail server you could just use python to do that.

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:25 | tee emails.log
```

Comment: That's a neat solution for simple email debugging, but we need some other features such as:
* Beeing able to clear the inbox
* Beeing able to imap the mail to check html-mails and attachements